# How Many Securities do CRAs Rate Every Year?

Tags: data-request, credit

I am writing a paper using [this](https://data.world/muni-finance/credit-ratings-history-data) database and want some idea of if the securities in this dataset are a comprehensive list of all the ratings that credit ratings agencies (CRAs) have done, or just a subset of them. Is there some place where the number of securities rated by a CRA in a given year is recorded? Or is there some holistic measure of the number of securities rated by each CRA in a given year?

My guess is that data after 2010 should be representative of the market as [CRAs are required to disclose all ratings](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/17/240.17g-7) to their website.